# How does one prove U(100) is not cyclic without computing the order of any element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

For starters, $|U(100)| = \varphi(100) = 40$. So by Lagrange, $\forall \hat{x} \in U(100), ord(\hat{x}) \mid 40$. Now, how can one prove there aren't any generators in U(100) without computing the order of any element?

Comment: You could take this opportunity to determine all $n$ such that $U(n)$ is cyclic. The answer is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n). It only requires the chinese remainder theorem, and the structure of $U(p^k)$ for $p$ prime. The only annoying case is $p=2$. But it does require to compute the order of some elements. So this is probably not helpful for your question, sorry.

Comment: Here you can just observe that the square of any odd intger is $\equiv1\pmod4$ and the twentieth power is $\equiv1\pmod{25}$. Therefore $n^{20}$ leaves remainder $1$ modulo both $4$ and $25$, and therefore also modulo $100$. In other words, CRT is your friend (as also suggested by julien).

Comment: @julien For posterity, it seems the answer I was looking for is the following:  
$U(100) = U(25 \cdot 4) \cong U(25) \oplus U(4)$.
And by Gauss, $U(25) \oplus U(4) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{20} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.
In $\mathbb{Z}_{20} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ the order of any element is at most lcm(20, 2) = 20.
Thus, there are no elements of order 40 in U(100), hence U(100) is not cyclic.

Comment: Petre, I recommend that you post that as an answer. That way this question won't get stuck in the unanswered files. You may also get more feedback/comments on your solution (not to mention the possibility of upvotes). Answering one's own question is very much kosher here (there may be a time window when you cannot, but it will expire soon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended in the comments, I'm posting here the answer I was looking for:
$U(100) = U(25⋅4) \cong U(25) \oplus U(4)$. By Gauss, $U(25) \oplus U(4) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{20} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. And since the order of any element in  $\mathbb{Z}_{20} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is at most lcm(20, 2) = 20, there are no elements of order 40 in U(100).
Thus, U(100) is not cyclic.